# Why my webpage is not working properly on phones but it works good at desktop

Tags: html

I am trying to make a webpage with HTML,css and jquery. But the problem is that the webpage is not working properly on phone or other small screen devices. Here is the [link](https://the-zed.000webhostapp.com/Bikerz.html) for the page.

Comment: Please use the bootstrap concept for responsive website design here is the link for the same http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. To have responsive layouts, use percentages for width/height and margins rather than pixels (px) so that they can auto-resize when the screen size changes. To make your bottom bike image look responsive, use `width: 95%` and `height: 95%` (or whatever other percentage you'd like). For the Bikerz icon, try using `margin:` Google Chrome's inspect feature is very useful so make sure to test it out on it. Simply right click on the web page and click Inspect. Once you are there you will see an icon left of the "Elements" section. When you click that, you can view your web page layout under different resolutions.

Comment: friend when I entered percentages they didn't worked .But thanks for your answer.

Comment: Great to hear that my solution helped out. Please hit the check icon to accept my answer if it helped you out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to write custom css to support mobile device or I will recommend to use [Bootstrap](http://developing%20responsive,%20mobile%20first%20projects%20on%20the%20web) framework in order make compatible your site on mobile. Bootstrap will allow you to developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.

If you are going to use css then, i will also recommend you to validate your css support at different browser and mobile platform through [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/).